# Automate loading data from S3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

> I want too load data from S3 to Redshift. The data coming to S3 in around 5MB{approximate size} per sec.

I need to automate the loading of data from S3 to Redshift.
The data to S3 is dumping from the kafka-stream consumer application.

The folder S3 data is in folder structure.
Example folder :
**bucketName/abc-event/2020/9/15/10**

files in this folder :

abc-event-2020-9-15-10-00-01-abxwdhf.  5MB

abc-event-2020-9-15-10-00-02-aasdljc.  5MB

abc-event-2020-9-15-10-00-03-thntsfv.  5MB

> the files in S3 have json objects separated with next line.

> This data need to be loaded to **abc-event** table in redshift.

I know few options like **AWS Data pipeline**, **AWS Glue**, **AWS Lambda Redshift loader** (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/).

What would be the best way to do it.
Really appreciate if someone will guide me.
Thanks you

=============================================

> Thanks Prabhakar for the answer. Need some help in continuation on this.

Created a table in Data Catalog by crawler and
then running a ETLL job in glue does the job of loading the data from S3 to redshift.

I am using approach 1. Predicate pushdown
New files get loaded in S3 in different partition say (new hour started.)

I am adding new partition using a AWS Glue python script job.
Adding new partition in the table using Athena API. (using ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION).

I have checked in the console that the new partition gets added by the python script job. I checked new partion gets added in Data catalog table.

When I run the same job with pushdown predicate giving same partition added by the python script glue job.

The job did not load the new files from S3 in this new partition to Redshift.

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong ???

Comment: how are you writing data to s3 from Kafka ? folder structure ? and you only write incremental data to s3 in source?

Comment: using aws sdk java writing to s3 ,yes it will be folder structure. every file is getting created bases on time partitioner. the data is of logs from various sources with many properties.

Comment: can you update your question with the actual folder structure that you are using? that is very important in deciding the approach that you can use with Glue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use case you can leverage AWS Glue to load the data periodically into redshift.You can schedule your Glue job using trigger to run every 60 minutes which will calculate to be around 1.8 GB in your case.

This interval can be changed according to your needs and depending on how much data that you want to process each run.

There are couple of approaches you can follow in reading this data :

1. [Predicate pushdown](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html) :

This will only load the partitions that mentioned in the job. You can calculate the partition values every run on the fly and pass them to the filter. For this you need to run Glue crawler each run so that the table partitions are updated in the table metadata.

If you don't want to use crawler then you can either use boto3 [create_partition](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_partition) or Athena [add partition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-partition.html) which will be a free operation.

2. [Job bookmark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html) :

This will load only the latest s3 data that is accumulated from the time that your Glue job completed it's previous run.This approach might not be effective if there is no data generated in S3 in some runs.

Once you calculate the data that is to be read you can simply write it to redshift table every run.

In your case you have files present in sub directories for which you need to enable `recurse` as shown in below statement.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database =<name>, table_name = <name>, push_down_predicate = "(year=='<2019>' and month=='<06>')", transformation_ctx = "datasource0", additional_options = {"recurse": True})
```

Comment: Thanks Prabhakar. I will definetely consider the given approaches. I was thinking of using AWS Lambda Redshift Loader(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/). Can you please have a look at it. As it also seems to be usecase which I want. And help me to differentiate between the two solutions. Thanks alot.

Comment: saw the blog and it looks like you need to maintain the state of processed files and looks like this pattern is very old where you need to setup lot of things to maintain metadata. In Glue you get all of these features inbuilt which you don't need to maintain.

Comment: Hi Prabhakar , Thanks for the answer, updated the question. after following the pushdown predicate approach u shared. Can you please have a look at it. Thanks alot.

Comment: Have you tried querying this table in Athena for the latest partition and see if it is giving appropriate result ? If it is then you might need to update your question with Glue ETL script that you have used to see why it is not loading the data properly.

Comment: yes I have checked in the console that the new partition gets added by the python script job. I checked new partion gets added in Data catalog table.

Comment: i think i figured out why you are not able to read the data. I have updated my answer with the sample script where you need to enable recurse option.

Comment: I figured out that while I am adding the partition from a python script job. In View properties of a partition I saw "location": "s3://bucketname//video-events/2020/partition_0=09/partition_1=24/partition_2=06".  and hence I guess that's why it is not picking up the new files. I am using "ALTER TABLE tableName ADD PARTITION(partition_0 ='09', partition_1='24',partition_2='05')".                 Where I am wrong here ??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be "location": "s3://bucketname//video-events/2020/09/24/06

Comment: you need to also specify the location as the s3 folders are not in key value format. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

Comment: Hi Prabhakar, Thank you very much for all the help.Being new in AWS.     So I am using the pushdown predicate approach. So The flow is like when the new data is get ingested in S3  , I will update the new partition by a python script glue job say (every hour.). Now I wanted the pipeline should do the transfer (s3 to redshift) as close to  realtime and with no duplicacy and fault tolerant. because the data is coming at high speed every second around 5mb data of file  gets generated. Can you please help in guiding the best way to achieve this. Thanks a lot for all the help. Thanks Prabhakar :)